# What is the purpose of Unique property in datatable in C#?

Tags: c#

Why do we use unique key in data table in C#?

i need answer with syntax..  how to set unique key

```
objDataColumn.Unique = objDataTable.Columns.Add("Student ID");
objDataTable.Columns.Add("Student Id", typeof(int));
```

thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple:

```
DataColumn dt = new DataColumn("Student ID", typeof(int));
dt.Unique = true;
objDataTable.Columns.Add(dt);
```

Or if you're a fan of one-liners:

```
objDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Student ID", typeof(int)) { Unique = true });
```

Answer (score 2):

Unique constraint will ensure your column will never have duplicate value.
[see msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.unique(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
DataColumn column = new DataColumn("Student ID");
column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
column.Unique = true;
objDataTable.Columns.Add(column);
```

Answer (score 0):

for primary key:

```
DataColumn[] keys = new DataColumn[1];
keys[0] = objDataTable.Columns[0];
objDataTable.PrimaryKey = keys;
```

for constraint:

```
var c= new UniqueConstraint(new DataColumn[] { objDataTable.Columns[0]});
objDataTable.Constraints.Add(c);
```